# Accordion - Don't want to make first cell active

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Well I am using [**jQuery accordion**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height). Below is what I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion001").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true
    });
});
```

The problem is that it always shows the first link data by default.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Link 1                            +
+     Link 1 line 1                   +
+     Link 1 line 2                   +
+     Link 1 line 3                   +
+   Link 2                            +
+   Link 3                            +
+   Link 4                            +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I don't want to show first link data. I just want to show all available links as below.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Link 1                            +
+   Link 2                            +
+   Link 3                            +
+   Link 4                            +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Is it doable? What option do I need to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#accordion001").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        active:false,
    });
```

this should work.

Comment: could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622069/jquery-accordian-de-collapse

Answer (score 0):

$( "#accordion001" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );

and it will be opened in load time.