# jQuery - Accordion (De-Collapse)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Well, this question is next version of my [**earlier question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621550/accordion-dont-want-to-make-first-cell-active).

As I have all links collapsed, I want to create one button OR link saying "Show All", on clicking it will make all links active in accordion i.e. I want to view data of all links. Also need to create one button OR link saying "Hide All" which will make collapsed state as earlier.

Collapsed State

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Link 1                            +
+   Link 2                            +
+   Link 3                            +
+   Link 4                            +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Should get after clicking "Show All"

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Link 1                            +
+     Link 1 line 1                   +
+     Link 1 line 2                   +
+     Link 1 line 3                   +
+   Link 2                            +
+     Link 2 line 1                   +
+     Link 2 line 2                   +
+     Link 2 line 3                   +
+   Link 3                            +
+     Link 3 line 1                   +
+     Link 3 line 2                   +
+   Link 4                            +
+     Link 4 line 1                   +
+     Link 4 line 2                   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How to do this?

Comment: this may help you http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multi-open-accordion/

Comment: If you want to keep them all expanded then you **shouldn't** use the standard Accordion. It's not the right control for that (as pointed out even on jQuery UI Accordion man page).

Comment: @Fahim Parkar check below my answer. it will meet your requirement. No need of accordian menu.

Comment: @Ravichandran : I am not talking about MENU... I am talking about ACCRDION....

Comment: @Adriano : Then what should I use?

Comment: Stacked collapsible panels, for example. I didn't check but the plug-in posted by krish may be what you need.

Comment: You could also use this togglePanels plugin: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-multiple-sections-open-at-once#14737000003074875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution to expand and collapse all content panels.

```
function expandAll() {
    $('#accordion h3').removeClass('ui-state-default')
        .addClass('ui-state-active')
        .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
        .addClass('ui-corner-top')
        .attr('aria-expanded', 'true')
        .attr('aria-selected', 'true')
        .attr('tabIndex', 0)
    .find('span.ui-icon')
        .removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e')
        .addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s')
    .closest('h3').next('div')
        .show();

    $('.expand').text('collapse all').unbind('click').bind('click', collapseAll);

    $('#accordion h3').bind('click.collapse', function() {
        collapseAll();
        $(this).click();
    });
}

function collapseAll() {
    $('#accordion h3').unbind('click.collapse');

    $('#accordion h3').removeClass('ui-state-active')
            .addClass('ui-state-default')
            .removeClass('ui-corner-top')
            .addClass('ui-corner-all')
            .attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
            .attr('aria-selected', 'false')
            .attr('tabIndex', -1)
        .find('span.ui-icon')
            .removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s')
            .addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e')
        .closest('h3').next('div')
            .hide();

    $('.expand').text('expand all').unbind('click').bind('click', expandAll);

    $('#accordion').accordion('destroy').accordion();
}
```

and the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wa9Dz/1/

Answer (score 0):

As a ***hack*** (*last resort*) you could use

```
// highlight headers
$("#accordion001").find('h3.ui-accordion-header')
                  .removeClass('ui-state-default')
                  .addClass('ui-state-active');

//open content panels
$("#accordion001").find('div.ui-accordion-content')
                  .addClass('ui-accordion-content-active')
                  .show();
```

But you will need to handle the closing as well (*undo what we did*) since the current code messes with the default behavior..